# wget always giving ERROR 404: Not Found

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

```
wget http://www.icerts.com/images/logo.jpg --header "Referer: www.icerts.com"
--2018-03-16 16:41:28--  http://www.icerts.com/images/logo.jpg
Resolving www.icerts.com (www.icerts.com)... 192.243.111.11
Connecting to www.icerts.com (www.icerts.com)|192.243.111.11|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.icerts.com/images/logo.jpg [following]
--2018-03-16 16:41:30--  https://www.icerts.com/images/logo.jpg
Connecting to www.icerts.com (www.icerts.com)|192.243.111.11|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-03-16 16:41:32 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Also not able to install any software using sudo apt-get install, it is always showing same ERROR 404: Not Found

Comment: That's giving me a 404 too. Are you sure it does exist? For apt you'd have to check what mirror you're trying to use and your network configuration I expect.